# Как выгрузить остатки товаров по складам и резервы

Tags: moysklad-json-api, мойсклад

Стоит задача выгрузить суммарное значение остатков товаров, остатки по складам и значение резервов. 
То есть если в МС есть товар на складе в количестве 1 штука, на него есть резерв 1 штука, нужно чтобы выгрузилась такая информация: суммарное количество остатков = 1, остаток на складе = 1, резерв = 1.
Синхронизация с интернет магазином заранее вычитает резервы из остатков и присылает доступное количество = 0.

Пробовал использовать - https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82

GET https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/assortment

Приходят данные по суммарному значение остатков, по резервам и по доступному количеству, но нет данных по значению остатков конкретно для каждого из складов.

Пробовал использовать -
https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-get

GET https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/report/stock/bystore

Приходят данные по остаткам на складах, но нет информации к какому из товаров относятся эти остатки.

Есть ли возможность получить нужную информацию для всех товаров?

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его, пожалуйста, как верный. Или уточните вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам должен подойти запрос остатков по складам https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/report/stock/bystore

Каждый объект в ответе содержит информацию о товаре (meta) и остатки для всех складов:

```
{  
  "meta":{  
    "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/268b8184-4fac-11e9-ac12-000a0000000c?expand=supplier",
    "metadataHref":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/metadata",
    "type":"product",
    "mediaType":"application/json",
    "uuidHref":"https://online.moysklad.ru/app/#good/edit?id=268a9be3-4fac-11e9-ac12-000a0000000a"
  },
  "stockByStore":[  
    {  
      "meta":{  
        "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/store/335be335-5082-11e9-ac12-000e00000051",
        "metadataHref":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/store/metadata",
        "type":"store",
        "mediaType":"application/json",
        "uuidHref":"https://online.moysklad.ru/app/#warehouse/edit?id=335be335-5082-11e9-ac12-000e00000051"
      },
      "name":"Второй",
      "stock":0,
      "reserve":0,
      "inTransit":0
    },
    {  
      "meta":{  
        "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/store/8822e67f-4ed0-11e9-ac12-000d0000005c",
        "metadataHref":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/store/metadata",
        "type":"store",
        "mediaType":"application/json",
        "uuidHref":"https://online.moysklad.ru/app/#warehouse/edit?id=8822e67f-4ed0-11e9-ac12-000d0000005c"
      },
      "name":"Основной склад",
      "stock":-2,
      "reserve":0,
      "inTransit":0
    }
  ]
}
```

В meta ссылка на товар: `"href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/268b8184-4fac-11e9-ac12-000a0000000c?expand=supplier"`

Comment: Тут приведен пример для товара, но нет примера для товара с модификациями. Как получить остатки для каждой модификации ведь тут только товар и в описании в методе тоже только товар?