# Есть ли возможность получить информацию для всех товаров в одном запросе /report/stock/bystore

Tags: мойсклад

По вопросу

> [Как выгрузить остатки товаров по складам и резервы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/961419/336407)

в ответе Дмитрий [написал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/962043/336407):

```
В meta ссылка на товар: "href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/268b8184-4fac-11e9-ac12-000a0000000c?expand=supplier"
```

Вот у меня как раз вопрос в продолжении данной темы. Можно ли одним запросом остатков по складам получить и информацию о товарах? Расширить ответ. Я пытался в https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/report/stock/bystore сделать expand=product но результата это не дало.

Как работать со ссылками в блоке "Мета". Доп запросами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, одновременно получить остатки и расширенное представление товаров нельзя.

Работа с expand описана в [инструкции](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-expand)

Comment: Как правильно, в таком случае поступить (the best practices), если есть тысяча-две-три товаров и нужен отчет, в простейшем варианте, с наименованием товара, остатками и резервами по складам?
Кешировать товары у себя и сопоставлять по информации из меты?

Comment: да, как вариант